# No virtual memory (-v) item in output of ulimit -a

Tags: memory, aix, limit, ulimit

When I run command `ulimit -a`, I see no virtual memory item in the list of output of the command. It is unlimited for some user IDs though.

Does that mean I am assigned no virtual memory?

Comment: I suggest you present the output from ulimit -a with this question.

Comment: *"Does that mean I am assigned no virtual memory?"* It could not possibly mean that, no.

Answer (score 0):

Different unix variants have different capabilities when it comes to limiting resource usage. [On AIX](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds5/ulimit.htm), there is no limit on the virtual memory used by a process, and consequently `ulimit` does not have a `-v` option. You can limit the heap size (`ulimit -d`) and the stack size (`ulimit -s`), which amounts to pretty much the same thing.